# Unity Animator Checking Too Slow

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm currently just trying to learn to use the animator within Unity, I'm very in-exp at animation and don't understand it even in the editor as I focus on programming/scripting.

I have an animation and the states for the animations as-well as the conditions all working perfectly however the animation check for the next state is way to slow. I've tried changing the speed of the actual state but it speeds the animation up and makes it look like my character is walking insanely fast.

I've tried messing around with the frames, making them over a longer time period and making the speed of the state faster however it seems to counter act each other, when I make it longer frames the pace of the animation is slow and then when I make the speed of the state go quicker it just makes the frames tick faster making the animation faster.

What I believe is happening is that the check for the next state of animation is happening once the full animation has been played. However what I need is the check to be happening constantly (as if frame by frame of the unity game not the animation).

Any advice would be great, I've tried using youtube to solve this before coming here however most people are creating a platformer game where as I'm trying to aim for a top down 2d, all directional character movement instead of the linear x axis character movement., and outside libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I deeply apologise for my inability to find a suitable source. I have literally just came across an article online that came across a simple solution.

here:https://answers.unity.com/questions/221601/slow-animation-response.html

basically if you can't be bothered to click the link and you are having the same problem,

find exit-time by clicking the transition and then in the inspector and untick it.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem myself, and the best solution I found was to simply give up on using GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo, and use this plugin instead to get reliable animation events.

https://github.com/beatrate/ReliableMecanimEvents

I was able to use this to accomplish a stateless design, but if you need to be able to get the current state at any time, you can use these events to set a data structure to keep track of the current animation clip.